# SpringBoot 2 YAML Properties Test Not Working

Tags: java, spring-boot, yaml, spring-boot-test

Trying to test yaml properties mapping to a pojo in Springboot 2.7.11 but the pojo keeps coming up as null.

src/test/resources/application-test.yml

```
configItems:
  items:
    - field1: name
      field2: address
    - field1: name
      field2: address
```

ConfigItems.java

```
@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "configItems")
@Getter
@Setter
public class ConfigItems {

  private List<Item> items;
  
  @Getter
  @Setter
  @NoArgsConstructor
  @AllArgsConstructor
  public static class Item {
    private String field1;
    private String field2;
  }
}
```

MapFromYamTest.java

```
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@SpringBootTest
@EnableConfigurationProperties(value = ConfigItems.class)
@ActiveProfiles("test")
public class MapFromYamlTest {
  
  @Autowired
  private ConfigItems configItems;

  @Test
  public void everythingMappedCorrectly() {
    assertNotNull(configItems, "Config is null");
  }
}
```

I've tried a number of annotation variations on the test hence why it is now using both the ExtendWith and SpringBootTest annotations. I've tried one or the other. I've tried variations of ContextConfiguration in addition to the other annotations. I just don't get why the assertion keeps failing...

Comment: What happens when removing the `@Configuration`?

Comment: @dan1st same failing assertion. I had `@Component` for a while as well as my hope is to inject it into other classes, but that didn't work either

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was with my @Test annotation...

I commented out almost the entire project and any dependencies. Finally took a look at my imports after it was still failing with nothing else remaining. I'm using Junit 5 as is obvious from the @ExtendWith annotation but what IntelliJ did was auto import

`import org.junit.Test` which is junit 4

and what I needed was `import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test` instead which is unit 5.

Unbelievable...

Comment: If you still have a mixture of junit 4 and 5 tests, it is time to update all the tests and exclude the old dependency. Quite the hassle to maintain both junit 5 and vintage tests.

Comment: @dcolzin couldn't agree more. I am excluding junit 4 in my pom.xml going forward. Something I didn't realize with Springboot, it just brings in both via transitive dependencies and you don't notice until your IDE suggests one over the other!

Comment: Had a really old version of Cucumber that was bringing in junit 4 despite springboot-starter-test having junit 5 only